# CSS3 HTML5: Side bars position

Tags: html, css

So I'm making a basic layout. Which I usually take a creative commons layout but this time I decided to build my own.

So basically I am making a very basic page where there is a top section 100% width.
Then under that we have a `display:table-cell` section to place the two sections side by side.

This seems to work but my `<h1></h1>` is being placed at the bottom portion of the area. I want the content to be at the very top.

Here is my code:

```
section  
{
    display: block;

}

#instructions 
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: bisque;
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

#picture 
{
    width: 100% auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color:  aliceblue;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 10px solid #000;
    display: table-cell;
}
#content 
{
    width: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 25px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Alberta Map</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Learning Alberta's Geography">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<section id="instructions">
<h1>Learning Altberta's Geography</h1>
    <p>bla bla bla bla</p>
</section>

<section id="picture">
    <img src="alberta.jpg"></img>    
</section>

<section id="content">
<h1> Lake....</h1>

</section>


</body>
```

What this outputs is the following problem:

[image]

Ultimately I want the text on the content id to start at the top portion of the section.

What should I have done and why is the  at the lower bottom of the section?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think all you need is `vertical-align:top`

```css
    #instructions {
      background-color: bisque;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    #picture {
      background-color: aliceblue;
      padding: 30px;
      border: 10px solid #000;
      display: table-cell;
    }
    #content {
      display: table-cell;
      padding: 25px;
      font-size: 16px;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
```

```html
<section id="instructions">
  <h1>Learning Altberta's Geography</h1>

  <p>bla bla bla bla</p>
</section>
<section id="picture">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-100-200-6.jpg" />
</section>
<section id="content">
  <h1> Lake....</h1>

</section>
```

Comment: Great. Thank you so much. Now I know. I have to wait 5 minutes to mark you as the answer. And why am I getting down voted?

Comment: @JPFoster I think the reason you got down voted was because in your original post, you didn't format you HTML as code, so it didn't actually show up when someone viewed the question. It was edited and fixed, but that was after the down vote had happened. So, in the future, try to remember to format HTML code using the 'Code Sample' button (which looks like an open and close curly brace). I may be wrong though, I'm just guessing.

Comment: Yea I did click it, but when I copy pasted it formatted oddly. Anyways. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

add

```
vertical-align:top;
```

to

```
#content
```

Answer (score 0):

That's right add vertical-align:top;